# Set Which EditText to focus when click "Next" on keyboard (Different Recycler View)

Tags: c#, android, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android, recyclerview-layout

I am creating a recycler view with each item have about 6 edit text. For e.g

**Item.axml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:maxLength="2"
    android:id="@+id/Box1"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="2"
    android:background="@drawable/statefocus"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#454B52" />
<EditText
    android:maxLength="2"
    android:id="@+id/Box2"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="2"
    android:background="@drawable/statefocus"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#454B52" />
<EditText
    android:maxLength="2"
    android:id="@+id/Box3"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="0"
    android:background="@drawable/statefocus"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#454B52" />
<EditText
    android:maxLength="2"
    android:id="@+id/Box4"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="2"
    android:background="@drawable/statefocus"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#454B52" />
<EditText
    android:maxLength="2"
    android:id="@+id/Box5"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="2"
    android:background="@drawable/statefocus"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#454B52" />
<EditText
    android:maxLength="2"
    android:id="@+id/Box6"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="0"
    android:background="@drawable/statefocus"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#454B52" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The item will be used on a standard recycler view. If I click on one of the textbox, the virtual keyboard will appear with next button, if I click on the next button, it will go to the second edittext, third, etc. (Yes, this is expected). But the sequence I want for my application is

1st box on **first item** then 2nd then 3rd. After that, instead of going to the 4th box, it goes to the 1st box on the **second item**. It goes until the 3rd box on the **last item**, after that if we click on Next Button, it will jump to the 4th box on the **First Item**. :

```
Item1(Box 1 - Box 2 - Box 3)  
Item2(Box 1 - Box 2 - Box 3)  
ItemN(Box 1 - Box 2 - Box 3)  
Item1(Box 4 - Box 5 - Box 6)  
Item2(Box 4 - Box 5 - Box 6)  
ItemN(Box 4 - Box 5 - Box 6)
```

**How to achieve this?** Thank you very much. I prefer Xamarin.Android (C#) Answer, but any Java / Native Android answer is ok too.

Comment: How many Item do you have? Is it dynamically added?

Comment: It is dynamically added. The total item is below 50